# How to import external modules in a Python package?

Tags: python, module

For example, module `m` in my package `p` uses `re`. I write `import re` in `m.py`. Some other module `n` also uses `re`. Do I write `import re` twice or include `import re` once in my `__init__.py`?

What's the convention for writing packages that include external modules?

Comment: I would `import re` in `m` and `n`, as that way each one can be read independently and clearly understood.

Answer (score 1):

Import re in each script (m and n). Then the scripts can be relocated to another package (if e.g. you refactor your code), and it is clearer from within the file what `re` is / where it is coming from etc.

Answer (score 1):

Import a module in every other module that uses it.

Python is intelligent about how that happens under the covers.  You can easily get into a Python form of DLL hell if you rely on indirect imports of modules.  Fortunately the indirect approaches are harder than the direct approaches :) so most people do the right thing somewhat naturally.